# How to detect a Pan Gesture inside a NSTouchBarView

Tags: macos, nstouchbar

Is it possible to detect a finger pan on a `NSTouchBarView`?

Sorry for the lack of code but I don't even know where to start.

MacOS is not made for finger touches but the TouchBar is but I do not see how to do it on a `NSTouchBarView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know specifically about using `NSTouchBarView`, but using a pan recognizer in a touch bar usually works like this: create a view, then create a `NSPanGestureRecognizer` (don't forget to set the target and action) then add the recognizer to the previously created view. Finally, create your `NSCustomTouchBarItem` and assign the previously created view to the item's view. Quick example in Swift:

```
func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItemIdentifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {

    switch identifier {
    case NSTouchBarItemIdentifier.yourCustomItem:
        return itemWithRecognizer(identifier: identifier)
    default:
        return nil
    }

}

func itemWithRecognizer(identifier: NSTouchBarItemIdentifier) -> NSTouchBarItem {
    let customView = NSView()
    customView.wantsLayer = true
    let recognizer = NSPanGestureRecognizer()
    recognizer.target = self
    recognizer.action = #selector(doSomething)
    customView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    let item = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
    item.view = customView
    return item
}

func doSomething() {
    // gesture was activated
}
```